# Is Børge R. Christensen, who defined the COMAL language 50 years ago, still with us?

Tags: programming-languages

Børge Christensen invented COMAL 50 years ago, and it became the standard language for teaching programming in schools in Denmark. Essentially it was BASIC but with structured programming constructs and most subsequent variants of BASIC followed this lead. I remember meeting Børge in 1980, but I don't recall his age then, and cannot find any biographical details. Does anyone (probably Danish) know if he is still around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am currently writing a book where Børge Christensen and Comal is playing an important role (https://www.thedanishcomet.com), i am also with the Danish Computer museum.

The short answer is, no Børge died way to early - if you want more details you are welcome to contact me directly, my contact info is on the website i linked above.